# Cron mysql database backup without mysql_dump

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have php mysql website and hosted on shared hosting. I have created a php script to take backup of database and email it via cron job.

But my hosting provider company is not allowing `mysql_dump function` with using password for security reason.

I have search and googled for the solution, But I got almost all searches with `system mysql_dump` only.

Is there any other way **to take backup of database** and **email it to given address** and doing this stuff **with cron job**.. ??

Comment: Can you please give your service provider name?

Comment: What is your Mysql Server version ? Do you have InnoDB tables in the database as well ? Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-methods.html